# Ionic Framework How to Implement Chat Heads

Tags: ionic-framework, frameworks

So how do we add facebook messenger alike chat heads to an ionic app? I am referring to a function same with this link

http://androidsrc.net/facebook-chat-like-floating-chat-heads/

So when clicking a chat head would open the app interface in an OVERLAY/POPUP way. Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty difficult task, first you need to create a plugin for chatheads and UI for chating, and then, create background servise, that appears chatheads and chating UI on multithread when message received/sent, synchronize with ionic app. I don't think if it is issue for hybrid app development, which runs on browser/webview.

Comment: Yep, having the message view as popup inside of the bubble could be tricky. I was trying to do it with a Microsoft project: http://microsoft.github.io/ace/docs/native-ui/#five but they just dropped their support